# Why isn't java.awt.image.BufferedImage serializable?

Tags: java, image, serialization, awt

I'm trying to serialize a `BufferedImage` in Java, but running my program I received a  `NotSerializableException`.

Looking at the `BufferedImage` class, I noticed that it does not implements `Serializable`.

Why doesn't `BufferedImage` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: I'm pretty there aren't any (or very few at least) BufferedXXX classes that are serializable.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058663/how-to-serialize-an-object-that-includes-bufferedimages, or quite similar I think. But it'd be interesting to know the reason why it can't be serialised. I think because it contains arch-specific raster data and endian.

Comment: @Fabio Bohnenberger Try to use `int[] getRGB(....)` and serialize the returned integer array instead of the image, and when you deserialize the array try to recreate your `BufferedImage` using the method `setRGB(....)`

Comment: BufferedImages can be *managed* —backed by platform-specific acceleration (such as graphics card texture memory).  Such features aren't particularly easy or useful to serialize.

Comment: @VGR it makes sense... So java provided the `ImageIcon` as an wrapper, that is simpler than `BufferedImage` and is `Serializable`

Comment: But, if there is something that shouldn't be serialized, this things must be transient, not all the class...

Comment: @FabioBohnenberger `ImageIcon` is actually a swing components which hold an Image, it is serializable, but should not be the solution to your question. You might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086868/how-to-send-images-through-sockets-in-java

Comment: Could you extend `BufferedImage` to a class `SerializableBufferedImage` that implements `Serializable`?

Answer (score 5):

I think you've just discovered a missing feature.

- Does it make sense to have `BufferedImage implements Serializable`? In my opinion it does. Especially if the `BufferedImage` was not loaded from a file, but created and drawn upon. But even if it's from a file, who cares where the stuff comes from if I want to exchange it between VMs via *RMI* or similar?
- Is there anything in `BufferedImage` that provides a strong technical reason against `BufferedImage implements Serializable`? I browsed the source code, and I don't think so.

I checked whether the bug database already contains an entry for that, and I couldn't find anything related. So, this is your chance to make your contribution and suggest a feature request via the bug database. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/

As a workaround, you might want to look at the implementation of `readObject()` and `writeObject()` in class `javax.swing.ImageIcon`. `ImageIcon` is `Serializable`. Maybe you can wrap the `BufferedImage` in an `ImageIcon` for your use case, or somehow otherwise provide the logic from `ImageIcon.readObject()` / `ImageIcon.writeObject()`.

Comment: Upvoted. It obviously *doesn't* apply to `javax.swing.ImageIcon.`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Why should an image not be `Serializable`? What's so special about an image compared to everything else?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard An image is only a file if you already have the file. If you don't have it, and you need it, you have to get it from somewhere else. Images aren't necessarily files at all: they can be generated dynamically. This really is not making any sense.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Sorry, I find that argument absurd. Somehow, you can turn everything into a file, that doesn't mean that Serialization doesn't make sense. By that definition, `javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument` shouldn't be `Serializable` either. Just because something has one or more commonly used file formats doesn't mean that direct serialization should not be provided. I see serialization primarily as a matter of convenience for programmers when exchanging data between VMs to actually not have to deal with storing stuff in separate files but simply dump an object graph.

Comment: Saving to a file is not a solution. For example, look at RMI. The two VMs might actually not be accessing the same file system. So somehow, there needs to be a byte stream between the two VMs.

Comment: It also doesn't address the object-graph issue.